# Method for returning the mode that occurs most frequently

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement

I need help on this problem:

Write the method mode that accepts an array of test grades(0 – 100) and return the mode, the grade that occurs most frequently. If there are multiple modes, return the smallest.

My code does not work: Please help, thanks!

```
public static int mode(int[] marks) {
    int count = 0;
    int count0 = 0;
    int mostFrequent = marks[0];
    for (int x = 0; x < marks.length; x++) {
        if (marks[x] == mostFrequent) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count>count0) {
       count0  = count;
       mostFrequent = marks[count];
    }
    return mostFrequent;
}
```

E.g:

If marks = {1,2,4,6,1,1,1}, it works

if marks = {1,2,4,1,3,2,3,5,5}, it does not work

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Are you getting an exception? Wrong results?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I am getting wrong results. It works sometimes and doesn’t other times.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to add an example of an input that doesn't work, the result you expect and what you get instead?

Comment: If you're going to do it with `for` loops, you'll need 2 nested loops. Take a step back, and re-think what you're doing. --- Alternatively, search the web for solutions, there are plenty out there.

Comment: Hi @FedericoklezCulloca, I edited it. Please take a look.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, Yes, I am sorry. I just changed the code as well.

Comment: You're only counting the frequency of the value in the first position of the array, so it just happens to work when the most frequent value is in that position too. Don't you think you need to count the frequencies of the other values in the array? As I already said: *Take a step back, and **re-think what you're doing***.

Answer (score 1):

You need to count the occurrence of all numbers. Try the following.

```
public static int mode(int[] marks) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    IntStream.of(marks).forEach(x -> myMap.merge(x, 1, Integer::sum)); // Take the occurences of each number
    Integer maxOccurence = Collections.max(myMap.values()); // Take the maximum
    return myMap.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == maxOccurence).findFirst().get().getKey(); // Take the first(smallest) key which matches the maximum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
 public static int mode(int[] marks) {
        return Arrays.stream(marks)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<Integer, Long>::getValue).reversed().thenComparing(Map.Entry<Integer, Long>::getKey))
                .findFirst()
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse(0);
    }
```

Note: the last line sets 0 as a default value in case the array which is passed is empty.

```
 .map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse(0);
```

If you want to throw an exception in such a case change it to:

```
 .map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
```